# Couldn't ping Oracle Solaris 11 via hostname

Tags: solaris, ping, hostname

I have various linux systems running under one dhcp server and two dns servers.

Someone told that you never register your hostname to dhcp server , you get ip from dhcp server and then register hostname to dns server (correct me if this is wrong) .

I generally install vmwaretools on the linux machines and configure the `/etc/hosts` file for hostname and `/etc/resolv.conf` for domain and dns servers .

The problem is with Oracle Solaris 11 Express 64 bit , even though the hostname is properly being displayed using `hostname` and `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` file is correct , i'm unable to ping it via hostname (although pinging via ip address works fine) .

The same settings were done on rhel , suse , centos , oracle linux and they are pingable using hostname , what could be the problem ? (both these files for these os's are same) .

It seems like the dns server is unable to pick hostname for oracle solaris but for others it does , since i dont have access to dhcp/dns server , what changes do i require on solaris for it to work ?

Comment: Did you enable the name-service/switch service?